# How to get the last seven days of one month's data in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used below SQL to get last day of the month, but I need last seven days of the month:

```
DECLARE @dt as DATETIME = '7/29/2018'
DECLARE @LastDayOfTheMonth as DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(Month, 1, DATEADD(DAY,1 - DAY(@dt),@dt)))

SELECT @LastDayOfTheMonth
```

I could also use this SQL function in order to get above result, but I need last 7 days of any month's records.

```
SELECT EOMONTH('7/29/2018')
```

Comment: I could also use this SQL function in order to get above result, but I need last 7 days of any month's records. -> SELECT EOMONTH('7/29/2018')

Comment: Do you mean the 7th day before the end of the month? Perhaps `DATEADD(day, -6, EOMONTH('7/29/2018'))`.

Comment: yes the 7th day before the end of the month. That worked! Thanks very much Dan. I really appriciate.

Comment: Please be very careful with regional, language-dependent, ambiguous date formats like `mm/dd/yyyy`. Much safer to use `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Aaron. I will use yyyymmdd format.

Answer (score 0):

Just use DATEADD again to take 1 to 6 more days off @LastDayOfTheMonth.

```
SELECT @LastDayOfTheMonth, DATEADD(DAY,-1,@LastDayOfTheMonth), ..
```

If you want to return 7 values from a function, suggest making it a table function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Mandy.  I appriciate your help.